# How to use Typescript Compiler API to resolve type references?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-compiler-api

Suppose I have the following interfaces:

```
interface Person {
 name: string;
}

interface Attendee {
 person: Person;
 id: number;
}
```

I have already figured out how to use the compiler API to extract string representations of every property's type, e.g.:

```js
{ 
 Attendee: {
  person: "Person",
  id: "number"
 }
}
```

Here's how I do it: https://github.com/jlkiri/tsx-ray/blob/master/src/index.ts.
It's a combination of `typeToString` and `getTypeOfSymbolAtLocation` of the Type Checker.

However I would like to resolve types likes `Person` to their definition so that I get:

```
{ 
 Attendee: {
  person: {
   name: "string";
  },
  id: "number"
 }
}
```

Is there API I can use to easily do this, or do I have to implement the logic myself?

Comment: Did you manage to find it? Looking for the same thing

Comment: This sounds hardly possible, given that your desired format cannot represent self-referential nested types.

Answer (score 0):

Check [ts-morph](https://github.com/dsherret/ts-morph/tree/latest/packages/ts-morph). I recently discovered it and it looks promising.

Here is a minimal code that can do what you want:

```
import {ClassDeclaration, Project} from 'ts-morph';

const project = new Project({);
project.addSourceFilesAtPaths("src/**/*.ts");
const allSourceFiles = project.getSourceFiles();

allSourceFiles.forEach(sourceFile => {
   const classes = sourceFile.getClasses();
   classes.forEach(cls => {
      console.log(`class ${cls.getName()} {`);
      const properties = cls.getProperties();
      properties.forEach(prop => {
         const type = prop.getType();
         if(type.isClassOrInterface()) {
            const typeSymbol = type.getSymbol();
            console.log(`    ${prop.getName()} : 
            ${typeSymbol?.getName()} {`);
            const clsDeclaration = typeSymbol?.getDeclarations()[0] as ClassDeclaration;
            const members = clsDeclaration.getMembers();
            members.forEach(m => {
            console.log(`        ${m.getText()}`);
            });
            console.log(`    }`);
        } else {
            console.log(`    ${prop.getName()} : ${type.getText()}`);
        }
     });
     console.log(`}`);
  });
})
```

For the following two files:

```
// ./src/property.ts
class Category {
  description: string;
  id: number;
}
export default Category;

// ./src/product.ts
import Category from './category';
class Product {
  name: string;
  price: number;
  category: Category;
}
export default Product;
```

you will get the following printout:

```
class Category {
    description : string
    id : number
}
class Product {
    name : string
    price : number
    category : Category {
        description: string;
        id: number;
    }
}
```